# missing libncurses.so.5

Tags: 12.04, ncurses, pascal

I was installing free pascal IDE on Ubuntu 12.04 at x64 AMD. When i run fp file it says:

```
./fp: error while loading shared libraries: libncurses.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I searched Google and found out that i have libncurses.so.5 library installed as

`/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libncurses.so.5.9`

and link pointing at it

```
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libncurses.so.5
```

So i created a link in /lib pointing at /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libncurses.so.5
Now fp file found library, but it's not pleased with it...

```
./fp: error while loading shared libraries: libncurses.so.5: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64
```

Is ok to create link to link?
Am i missing a library or is it just not installed correctlly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are trying to run a 32-bit binary on a 64-bit system. You need to delete the link you created, and instead install `libncurses5:i386` so that you have the 32-bit version installed as well. It should be ported to Multi-Arch in 12.40, but you may have problems with some libraries and applications as not all of them are ported on 12.04.